# weak convergence in dense subspace

Tags: sequences-and-series, weak-convergence

given an arbitrary real step function $T$ and a sequence $w_n$ of real functions such that $ \lim_{n \to \infty}\int_a^b w_nT~ dx \to 0.$ Conclude that for every $v \in L_p([a,b]), \lim_{n \to \infty}\int_a^b w_nv~ dx \to 0,$ Note: step functions lie dense in $L_p([a,b]).$

My first thought was $\lim_{n \to \infty}\lim_{m \to \infty} \int_a^b w_nv~ dx =\lim_{n \to \infty}\lim_{m \to \infty}\int_a^b w_nT_m~ dx$(almost everywhere) and now I could switch lim's. But think I have to work with $\|v-T_m\| \to 0 $ somehow. Tips a very much appreciated.

Comment: I think the wording of the setting is flawed. It should read as follows: "Given a sequence $w_n$ of real functions such that $\int_a^bw_nT\,dx\to 0$ for any step function (which you will have to define here!). Then..."

Comment: Also, I think $(w_n)$ has to be uniformly bounded in $L^q$.

Comment: sry, your right I forgot it, $w_n \in L_p$ and uniformly bounded.

Comment: Then, I think, this is not correct. If, however, $w_n\in L^q$ (not $L^p$), this is trivial by Hölder's inequality.